# What is ある role here?

Tags: words, syntax

I don't understand why ある is in this sentence:

> 彼らは無事に、昨日**ある**島に上陸した。

Comment: How do you understand ある?

Comment: I don't get why ある is here.

Comment: I was not asking you to repeat what you wrote in question. I asked how do you understand ある. Sorry, if my question wasn't clear enough.

Comment: I know what ある means, but not in this sentence.

Comment: I did not ask you, **if** you know what ある means, but **how** do you understand ある. Is my question really unclear?

Comment: It means to exist, to be, to have. Didn't you understand my question?

Comment: ある means "certain" and 島 means "an island". Together they mean "a certain island". Yes, I do not understand your question and asked for a clarification.

Comment: I see it now, sorry for my foolish answers.

Comment: ↓ 100%辞書のコピペで事足りるならフォーラムで聞く必要ないやん！

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ある島:  a certain island, some island

Excerpt from [小学館プログレッシブ和英中辞典](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/je/2002/meaning/m0u/%E6%88%96%E3%82%8B/):

> ある【或る】 a certain; one; some
>
> ある所に: at [in] a certain place
> ある教授がそう言った: A certain professor said so.
> ある日: one day
> ある時: once
> ある場合には: in some cases
>
> 私はそう思うが，ある者はそう思わない。
> I think so, but some people don't.
>
> ある程度目的を達した。
> They achieved their purpose 「to some degree [to a certain extent].
>
> ある意味ではそれは正しい。
> That is correct in a (certain) sense.

Answer (score 6):

ある in this sentence is not a verb meaning "*to exist*, *to be*", but a prenominal adjective to 島{しま} and means "*certain*, *some*"

> [**ある** (或る)](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%88%96%E3%82%8B-428399)
>
> ［連体］《動詞「あり」の連体形から》はっきり名を挙げずに物事をさす語。また、漠然と物事をさしていう語。「或る所」「或る日」「或る人」

Comment: If we *did* interpret it as a verb, following the normal rules for modifying nouns with predicate clauses, grammatically we would get "a day which exists" - which is *not that far, semantically* from "a certain day".

Answer (score 6):

### There are 3 ways to express different meanings of ある with Kanji:

> **在る** - compare with 在宅{ざいたく}

- 「家に在る」
- "(it) is in the house"

> **有る** - compare with 有権者{ゆうけんしゃ}

- 「権利の有る者」
- "(a) person with (the) right" - *like the right to vote*

> **或る** - compare with 某日{ぼうじつ}

- 11月の或る日{ひ} - could also be expressed as,「11月某日」
- "a day in November" - *not any day specifically, just **a** day in general*

---

So the example in the OP could be written this way:

> 彼らは無事に、昨日**或{あ}る**島に上陸した

- They landed safely on **an** island yesterday - *not any specific island, just some island in general*

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer because it explains the usage requested in the question, while contrasting with other "versions" of ある.